# updatepanel slow to update after inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

After 2 minutes of inactivity, it's taking around 3 times as long to render an update panel on the page as it does before then. I understand it's probably the application pool settings but is there a way to avoid the issue by periodically making contact with the server from the page?

Comment: Could it be that your server threads are full? is this IIS, Apache?

Comment: IIS, but I'd like to just stay in contact with the server from the page rather than change IIS.

Comment: I wasn't going to suggest that at all. Let me know if this is what you're looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Comment: Maybe, thanks. I've tried using a jquery request but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this ->

```
function poll(){
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "mypage.asp", 
    success: function(data){
      //update the panel
      $("#panel").html(data);
    },
    dataType: "myDataType",
    complete: poll,
    timeout: 30000 });
  });
}
poll();//run pull at page load
```

This will send an ajax request to mypage.asp, update the panel with an id of #panel with the data returned, when the function completes it will perform the action again. The timeout for the event is set to 30 seconds.

I believe this will keep the event alive for you.

Comment: I don't want to update the panel, just do whatever is necessary to prevent the event that causes the lag. If that's because the worker pocess is shutting down, then prevent that.

Comment: This is a method of long polling. you don't have to perform anything in the success function. infact, you can remove it.